# Pinia lost its types when using factory pattern

Tags: typescript, pinia

for the need of my project I need to create a storeFactory to modulate the creation of a pinia store.

I specifically removed the parameters here and simplified the code example.

When I'm in File A, the type of storeFactory is automatically retrieved correctly

When I'm file B the type is lost and only this can be inferred

```
StoreDefinition<"store_id", {} | _UnwrapAll<Pick<any, string | number>>, {} | Pick<...>, {} | Pick<...>
```

### File A

```
export function storeFactory() {
  const baseEntityComponents = {}
  const extensionComponents = {}

  return defineStore(`store_id`, () => ({ // type OK
    ...baseEntityComponents,
    ...extensionComponents,
  }));
}
```

### File B

```
import {storeFactory} './fileA.ts'
export const useStore = storeFactory(); // type lost
```

### Question

How can we preserve the automatic type while wrapping the define store in a factory method?
If automatic type inferring is not possible, is there a way to define manually the type. I created an interface with all methods from the store but it's obviously not the same type as a instance of a pinia store containing those methods.